# What is the use of numpy.c_ in this code?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

what does `np.c` means in this code. Learning it from Udemy

```
df_cancer = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target'], columns=np.append(cancer ['feature_names'],['target;]))
```

Comment: What did the documentation tell you?

Comment: no i was just learning the code through the video so i didn't exactly understand what it was

Comment: That's alright. But before asking for help, try to solve the mild challenges you face on your own first. Python and most of its third-party libraries have very good documentation. You might also consider reading a proper python tutorial first, in case you're not familiar with it already. And if you see a name you're not familiar with: look up the documentation.

Comment: sure sure thanks man

Comment: `np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target']'` (added a missing ']' joins two columns, probably Series from the `cancer` dataframe.  It's a somewhat obscure expression for column concatenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to official NumPy [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html?highlight=c_#numpy.c_),

**numpy.c_** translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis.

**Example 1:**

```
>>> np.c_[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]

array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

**Example 2:**

```
>>> np.c_[np.array([[1,2,3]]), 0, 0, np.array([[4,5,6]])]

array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```